# ng-include doesn't do anything

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm trying to include some HTML on my software's webpage using ng-include, and I can't seem to get it to work. For now, I am using simplified versions of my end goals for testing purposes.

**Relevant snippet of my project tree:**

```
-web
--dragonweb
---src
----app
-----dragon
-------dragon.css
-------dragon.html
-------dragon.spec.ts
-------dragon.ts
-------test.html
```

**dragon.html**

```
<div ng-app = "" ng-controller="test">
    testing
    <div ng-include="" src="'app/src/dragon/test.html'"></div>
</div>
```

**test.html**

```
<div>
    This is an included file
</div>
```

**Expected output on the web page:**

testing

This is an included file.

**Actual output on the web page:**

testing

I've tried using different lengths of the path to test.html, with no luck. I've also been playing around with the use of the ng-controller tag, and syntax for the ng-include tag, with no luck. There are no console errors in the web page. Any idea why it doesn't seem to be working?

Backstory/disclaimer: I was the intern on this project before inheriting it after the lead dev suddenly left, this is my first time doing any sort of web development, and I'm just learning on the job from trial and error. So if I'm doing things wildly incorrect, I am absolutely all ears for how I can improve this process! I chose to try to use ng-include because we already have Angular implemented, and based on my research this seemed like the theoretically easiest way to accomplish what I wanted.

Comment: Chekc this out:: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude
You can try doing a relative url to see if it lodas: EX: `src="'./test.html'"></div>`

Comment: Check the Developer Console for errors. Since the code uses `ng-app=""`, the `ng-controller="test"` directive will create a runtime error. `Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'test' is not registered.`
https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.5/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=test

Comment: Thanks for the input! Unfortunately, no matter what I change, there are no console errors created regarding this. There are several console errors that were there before I inherited control of this project, so I am assuming (hoping?) that they aren't related.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the src to ng-include directive not the src attribute:
Ex:

```
<div ng-include="'app/src/dragon/test.html'"></div>
```

or use relative path:

```
<div ng-include="'./test.html'"></div>
```

Please check out the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) for details

**Usage**:
as **element**:

```
<ng-include
  src="'string_url'">
...
</ng-include>
```

as **attribute**:

```
<ANY_ELEMENT_TAG
  ng-include="'string_url'">
...
</ANY_ELEMENT_TAG>
```

**as CSS class:**

```
<ANY class="ng-include: string; [onload: string;] [autoscroll: string;]"> ... </ANY>
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited dragon.html to look like:  `<div ng-app = "" ng-controller="test">
    testing
  <div ng-include="'./test.html'"></div>
</div>
` and it still doesn't work. Is there a possibility there's another piece of the project that's not allowing something like this to work? I'm very new to using Angular and web development, so I'm not entirely sure what underlying problems might be affecting this.

Comment: I experimented with using it as an element `<ng-include src="'./test.html'"></ng-include>`, and it tells me "ng: 'ng-include' is not a known element...". Is this possibly my issue? And if so, how do I very that it's part of the module?

Comment: Why do you have `ng-app` as "". The ng-app should have some value, this attaches the angular to DOM

Comment: If this is not working, check the browser console if there are any 404's.  make sure you have ng-app outside of the ng-include!

Comment: Honestly just following people's examples when trying to troubleshoot ng-include. If I put a value in ng-app, does it need to correspond to anything else? And like I said, nothing I've tried has produced any console errors.

Comment: the ng-app should point to your angular app and should be used at your index html body or the container that contains your angular app. ng-app just before your ng-include should be empty